# Repel Objects when mouse is near

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of span elements in random positions enclosed inside a parent div called '.background'. These are generated with Javascript. Like this:

```
<span class="circle" style="width: 54px; height: 54px; background: #5061cf; top: 206px; left: 306px"></span>
```

I want them to move away (or repel) as the mouse draws near, but I have no idea how to do this! How would I go about accomplishing this in jQuery?

I imagine you'd have to search for spans that were nearby, and then change their position if they were inside a certain radius surrounding the mouse, but I really don't know where to start. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A simple approach would be to wrap each span in another, larger span. Make it larger on each side by the minimal distance you want the mouse to be able to approach the inner spans. Bind a function (`evade`) that moves each wrapper to [`mouseover`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) on the wrappers. This approach gives you a square border, so if the graphical elements in the inner spans aren't square, the distance from the mouse to the graphical element's border won't be constant, but is easy to implement.

Alternatively, use the bumper for a rough proximity test. Instead of binding the evade function to `mouseover`, bind a function (`beginEvade`) that binds `evade` on mousemove. Also, bind a function to `mouseout` that unbinds `evade`. Your `evade` can then perform a more precise proximity test.

First, find a good geometry library that provides a vector type. In absence of one, here's a sample implementation:

```
Math.Vector = function (x,y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
Math.Vector.prototype = {
    clone: function () {
        return new Math.Vector(this.x, this.y);
    },
    negate: function () {
        this.x = -this.x;
        this.y = -this.y;
        return this;
    },
    neg: function () {
        return this.clone().negate();
    },
    addeq: function (v) {
        this.x += v.x;
        this.y += v.y;
        return this;
    },
    subeq: function (v) {
        return this.addeq(v.neg());
    },
    add: function (v) {
        return this.clone().addeq(v);
    },
    sub: function (v) {
        return this.clone().subeq(v);
    },
    multeq: function (c) {
        this.x *= c;
        this.y *= c;
        return this;
    },
    diveq: function (c) {
        this.x /= c;
        this.y /= c;
        return this;
    },
    mult: function (c) {
        return this.clone().multeq(c);
    },
    div: function (c) {
        return this.clone().diveq(c);
    },

    dot: function (v) {
        return this.x * v.x + this.y * v.y;
    },
    length: function () {
        return Math.sqrt(this.dot(this));
    },
    normal: function () {
        return this.clone().diveq(this.length());
    }
};
```

Next, a sample circular evasion function (which is the simplest to implement). Outline:

1. calculate the bumper's center (the bumper's [corner](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) plus the [outer dimensions](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) divided in half)
2. calculate the mouse offset vector (from the [mouse cursor](http://api.jquery.com/event.pageX/) to the element's center)
3. proximity test: if the distance is >= the minimum allowed distance, then return early.
4. calculate delta: The distance to the mouse cursor is too small, so we need the vector from where the bumper is to where it should be (the delta). Lengthening the offset vector so it's the minimum allowed distance gives where the bumper's center should be, relative to the mouse's position. Subtracting the offset vector from that gives the delta from the proximity edge to the mouse, which also happens to be the delta.
5. calculate new position:

   1. add the delta to the current position.
   2. bounds checking: keep all borders of the circle within the document.
6. move the bumper

In code:

```
function evade(evt) {
    var $this = $(this),
        corner = $this.offset(),
        center = {x: corner.left + $this.outerWidth() / 2, y: corner.top + $this.outerHeight() / 2},
        dist = new Math.Vector(center.x - evt.pageX, center.y - evt.pageY),
        closest = $this.outerWidth() / 2;

    // proximity test
    if (dist.length() >= closest) {
        return;
    }

    // calculate new position
    var delta = dist.normal().multeq(closest).sub(dist),
        newCorner = {left: corner.left + delta.x, top: corner.top + delta.y};

    // bounds check
    var padding = parseInt($this.css('padding-left'));
    if (newCorner.left < -padding) {
        newCorner.left = -padding;
    } else if (newCorner.left + $this.outerWidth() - padding > $(document).width()) {
        newCorner.left = $(document).width() - $this.outerWidth() + padding;
    }
    if (newCorner.top < -padding) {
        newCorner.top = -padding;
    } else if (newCorner.top + $this.outerHeight() - padding > $(document).height()) {
        newCorner.top = $(document).height() - $this.outerHeight() + padding;
    }

    // move bumper
    $this.offset(newCorner);
}
```

After that, all that's left are functions to bind/unbind `evade`, and the calls to set everything up.

```
function beginEvade() {
    $(this).bind('mousemove', evade);
}

function endEvade() {
   $(this).unbind('mousemove', evade);
}

$(function () {
    // you can also wrap the elements when creating them.
    $('.circle').wrap('<span class="bumper" />')

    $('.bumper').bind('mouseover', beginEvade);
    $('.bumper').bind('mouseout', endEvade);
});
```

You can preview this in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/outis/bA8YE/1/)

Comment: But not [perfect](http://jsfiddle.net/outis/bA8YE/39/). z-indices cause problems with more than one evader.

Comment: hahaha that JSfiddle is fun to play with, I can imagine using it for a link that says 'CLICK ME!'  and then not being able to.

Answer (score 1):

you select all objects with class circle with jQuery, put that in a variable and then check on mousemove (could also ae done with jQuery) by looping through them if one is in certain radius from the mouse.

Comment: give each span an id and save all positions before doing this so you dont have to recalculate each time.

Answer (score 0):

This question and answer were very useful as a starting place for a script I wrote to repel an image with the cursor. I've iterated on the previous answer to support rectangular elements, instead of only square elements. The example code I've included below also uses web APIs instead of the jQuery library, so code will run in the browser without any additional dependencies, and it also takes window scrolling into account when moving the repelled image around.

A JSFiddle example is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/picnic_chin/9uas0x6m/21/), and the same code is included below.

```js
// Get the element that will evade the mouse
const bumper = document.getElementById("bumper")

// Pass the element to the parent function `evadeTheMouse`
evadeTheMouse(bumper)

function evadeTheMouse(element) {
  if (!element) {
    return
  }

  element.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
    // Get the location of the window, element, and mouse
    const {
      scrollX,
      scrollY
    } = window
    const {
      clientX: mouseX,
      clientY: mouseY
    } = e
    const {
      top,
      left,
      right,
      bottom,
      height,
      width
    } = element.getBoundingClientRect()

    // Exit early if the mouse isn't overlapping
    const mouseIsIntersecting = mouseX >= left && mouseX <= right && mouseY >= top && mouseY <= bottom
    if (!mouseIsIntersecting) {
      return
    }

    // Create vectors for each coordinate to more easily do math operations
    const windowScrollV = new Vector(scrollX || 0, scrollY || 0)
    const mouseV = new Vector(mouseX, mouseY)
    const centerV = new Vector(left + width / 2, top + height / 2)
    // Calculate where the line from the center to mouse will extend
    // into the edge of the image
    const targetV = getIntersectingPoint({
      top,
      left,
      right,
      bottom,
      height,
      width
    }, centerV, mouseV)
    // Calculate how far the mouse is from the edge of the image
    // (where it should be)
    const deltaV = mouseV.subtract(targetV)
    // Move the corner of the image the same amount, plus add
    // the scroll location to the calculated coordinates
    const newTopLeftV = new Vector(left, top).add(deltaV).add(windowScrollV)

    if (newTopLeftV.x < 0) {
      newTopLeftV.x = 0;
    }
    if (newTopLeftV.y < 0) {
      newTopLeftV.y = 0;
    }

    // Set the new element's position
    element.style.setProperty("position", "absolute")
    element.style.setProperty("top", `${newTopLeftV.y}px`)
    element.style.setProperty("left", `${newTopLeftV.x}px`)
  })
}

/**
 * Find the point where the vector from the center of the HMTL element
 * to the mouse will intersect with the edge of the HTML element
 * @param {HTMLElement} element The HTML element
 * @param {Vector} center A vector representing the element's center coordinates
 * @param {Vector} mouse A vector representing the mouse coordinates
 * @param {boolean} [debug=false] Option to draw shapes to help with debugging
 * @returns {Vector} The vector of the intersection
 */
function getIntersectingPoint(element, center, mouse) {
  const edges = findNearestEdges(element, center, mouse)

  // Calculate the intersecting point for the two closest edges.
  // One edge will have an intersecting point on the edge of the element.
  for (let i = 0; i < edges.length; i++) {
    const edge = edges[i]
    const slope = getSlope(center, mouse)
    const {
      solveForX,
      solveForY
    } = getEquations(slope, mouse)
    if (edge.x === undefined) {
      const {
        y
      } = edge
      const x = solveForX(y)
      if (x <= element.right && x >= element.left) {
        return new Vector(x, y)
      }
    } else if (edge.y === undefined) {
      const {
        x
      } = edge
      const y = solveForY(x)
      if (y <= element.bottom && y >= element.top) {
        return new Vector(x, y)
      }
    } else {
      throw new Error("Unable to find intersecting point")
    }
  }
}

/**
 * @typedef {object} Edge
 * @property {number|undefined} x
 * @property {number|undefined} y
 */

/**
 * Find the two edges of an HTML element that are closest
 * to the mouse hovering over it
 * @param {HTMLElement} element The HTML element
 * @param {Vector} center A vector representing the element's center coordinates
 * @param {Vector} mouse A vector representing the mouse coordinates
 * @returns {Edge[]} An array of the two closest edges with either an `x` or `y` value
 */
function findNearestEdges(element, center, mouse) {
  const edges = []
  if (mouse.x <= center.x) {
    // Mouse is on the left
    edges.push({
      x: element.left,
      y: undefined
    })
  } else {
    // Mouse is on the right
    edges.push({
      x: element.right,
      y: undefined
    })
  }

  if (mouse.y <= center.y) {
    // Mouse is on the top
    edges.push({
      x: undefined,
      y: element.top
    })
  } else {
    // Mouse is on the bottom
    edges.push({
      x: undefined,
      y: element.bottom
    })
  }

  return edges
}

/**
 * Calculate the slope of the line between two vectors
 * @param {Vector} point1
 * @param {Vector} point2
 * @returns {number}
 */
function getSlope(point1, point2) {
  return (point2.y - point1.y) / (point2.x - point1.x)
}

/**
 * Returns two functions that calculate coordinates
 * on the same line, given either an `x` coordinate
 * or a `y` coordinate
 * @param {number} slope The slope of a line
 * @param {Vector} point A known point on the line
 */

function getEquations(slope, point) {
  /**
   * @param {number} x The `x` coordinate on the line
   * @returns {number} The `y` coordinate on the line
   */
  function solveForY(x) {
    return slope * x - slope * point.x + point.y
  }

  /**
   * @param {number} y The `y` coordinate on the line
   * @returns {number} The `x` coordinate on the line
   */
  function solveForX(y) {
    return (y - point.y + slope * point.x) / slope
  }

  return {
    solveForX,
    solveForY
  }
}

/**
 * A vector with (`x`, `y`) coordinates and methods for
 * basic vector math operations
 */
class Vector {
  /**
   * Create a vector
   * @param {number} x The x coordinate
   * @param {number} y The y coordinate
   */
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
  }

  /**
   * @param {Vector} v2
   */
  add(v2) {
    return new Vector(this.x + v2.x, this.y + v2.y)
  }

  /**
   * @param {Vector} v2
   */
  subtract(v2) {
    return new Vector(this.x - v2.x, this.y - v2.y)
  }

  /**
   * @param {number} factor A number to multiply the vector by
   */
  multiply(factor) {
    return new Vector(this.x * factor, this.y * factor)
  }

  /**
   * @param {number} factor A number to divide the vector by
   */
  divide(factor) {
    return new Vector(this.x / factor, this.y / factor)
  }

  length() {
    return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y)
  }

  normalize() {
    return this.divide(this.length())
  }
}
```

```css
#circle {
  display: block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #5061cf;
}

#bumper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  left: 200px;
  padding: 32px;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<span id="bumper">
  <span id="circle" />
</span>
```