# How to make Jquery or CSS3 Animated "Catch me if you can" button?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I would like to create an animation button by using pure CSS or Jquery to make a joke for my visitors on April 1th. Basically, this will be regular button but when user hover on, it will move rapidly to the other side of the mouse. It is a simple game. But it should not be so difficult to catch. User may click on it if he/she try hard :)

Can anyone help me to create this?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try searching? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058308/repel-objects-when-mouse-is-near

Comment: @BillyMoat c'mooon 3000 lines of code for what?

Comment: @roXon - I wasn't suggesting that one was the perfect solution. I was just trying to encourage the OP to search first seeing as they haven't even posted any code up for what they've initially tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$("button").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css({
        left:(Math.random()*300)+"px",
        top:(Math.random()*300)+"px",
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZQamp/

---

Thanks to @roXon suggestion with much more better animation: http://jsfiddle.net/ZQamp/3

Comment: I don't see any problem with this. If a game that I cannot see any way to win, I'll probably never play it the second time

Comment: `But it should not be so difficult to catch. User may click on it if he/she try hard :)`

Comment: +1 Oh, sorry I needed to read carefully the Q. :) to not piss off the users: http://jsfiddle.net/ZQamp/3/ And any way you don't need "PX"

Comment: It works like i need but the button should not go to top or down. Just  to left and right rapidly. I guess we need to get the mouse coordinates to do that. Right?

Comment: No, I just want to express my opinion only. Thanks for your suggestion as well :)

Comment: @MegAnn Yes, you're correct but the problem is which direction your button need to move when user hover it

Comment: @user1479606, If the button is floated to the right whenever user hovering it, the button will go to the left. It will do same animation for the left side.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .block
            {
                position: absolute;
                left: 50px;
                width: 130px;
                height: 30px;
                margin: 5px;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="ReferencetoYourJqueryFile" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="block">
            <input type="button" name="btnClick" value="Catch me if you can" style="width: 130px;
                height: 30px; border: 1px sold silver; background-color: #f7dfb5" />
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(".block").mouseover(function () {
                $(".block").animate({ 
                        left:(Math.random()*500),
                        top:(Math.random()*500),
                 }, "fast");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```